# How to use GeoFire with firebase web version 9

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I'm using firebase realtime database web sdk v9 in my project and i want to add GeoFire but [the API Reference](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/master/docs/reference.md) explain only how to add it in web sdk v8

Is sdk v9 support GeoFire ? and how to add it to web sdk v9 project?

Comment: It can be used with compat version as in this [Github issue](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/issues/233) but the modular version seems to be [WIP](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/pull/217)

Comment: i saw this issue but what is the best solution for that , i can't simply use compat version because all functions in my app uses modular version